# Python reversing slice of a list

Tags: python, list

How do I reversed or iterate a list using its index?

Here is an example

```
lst = [3,2,4,1,5]
```

Output would be: `[3,2,4,5,1]` (index 3 which is 1 is place in the end)

Another example:

```
lst = [1,5,4,2,3]
```

Output: `[1,5,4,3,2]` (index 3 which is 2 is place in the end)

It is like the list is been reversed by using slicing.

Comment: You've asked 13 questions and not accepted any answers. Please remember to click the check mark next to the answer that solved your problem the best. You should go back to your old questions and do it for them, too.

Comment: i'm sorry. can you help me out with this?

Comment: I've already check the check mark. thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to reverse the part of a list past a certain point, the most straightforward way would be:

```
output = (lst[:3] # take the list before element 3
          + # and add
          lst[3:] # the list from element 3 on
          [::-1] # reversed
         )
```

or, without the comments:

```
output = lst[:3] + lst[3:][::-1]
```

If you want to change the existing list, you can:

```
lst[3:] = lst[3:][::-1]
```